# Easymock expectLastCall

Tags: unit-testing, junit, easymock

I am using Easymock with junit for writing my unit tests. I have a doubt in this regard and I could not find a very lucid explanation regarding it.
**How do you test void methods** ?
Since they do not return anything, so something like :

```
Easymock.expect(myMockObject.func(easymock.isa(String.class))).andReturn("NOTHING TO RETURN HERE");
```

above would not work as I have nothing to return.
So, how do I set my expectation and how to test a void method ?
I came to know that something like easymock.expectLastCall() would fit in but I am not sure as to what it does and why do we need it.
A lucid explanation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First with easymock you aren't testing the method that you want to test, you are mocking the methods it calls.
For example:

```
public void doSomething(){
  i = otherObject.foo();
  otherObject.bar();
}
```

The method `doSomething()`, is the method you wanted to test. `i` is a member variable of your class, let's say an integer. The calls `otherObject.foo()` and `otherObject.bar()` are method calls on another object that could be mocked (Mayby they are hard to set up, and you just want to mock them...). Now suppose that `bar()` is a void method, then for `otherObject.foo()` you could setup a normal expect, but for `bar()` you will need `expectLastCall()`.

When you test a void method (`doSomething()`), you want to check it's side effects... Did it change the collection? Did it create a new Object? Or, in this example, did the value of `i` change?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Please explain this : When we set up a normal easymock expectation, we specify that which method when called should return what(something like easymock.expect(obj.func()).andReturn(.....) but with expectLastCall, you do not specify the method which is being mocked ? Then, how does it know which method call to mock ?
I mean what if we have a series of 3 void method calls. How to use expectLastCall in such a scenario ?

Comment: @KumarMrinal you call the method, and the call easymock.expectLastCall(). Using the given example, we first do the setup for foo, then for bar: easymock.expect(otherObject.foo()).andReturn(.....) ; otherObject.bar(); EasyMock.expectLastCall();

Comment: So, if the method to be tested is something like : 
public void doSomething(){ 
  i = otherObject.foo(); 
  otherObject.bar();
  otherObject.set(); 
  otherObject.put(); 
} 
then, to test this scenario, we would have to write something like : 
easymock.expect(otherObject.foo()).andReturn(.....) ;  // for foo 
otherObject.bar(); EasyMock.expectLastCall(); // for bar 
otherObject.set(); EasyMock.expectLastCall(); // for set 
otherObject.put(); EasyMock.expectLastCall(); // for put 

I mean one expectLastCall for each preceding void method ?

Comment: Good question! If I remember correctly you can call it once and specify the number of calls: expectLastCall().times(4);